# Is VARCHAR or INT a validation rule?

Tags: sql, database

When I set up a table, is declaring the 'name' attribute as varchar make this a validation rule or does this just define the data type?

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

what I'm confused over is whether VARCHAR sets a data type, a validation rule or both of these things. So in a way VARCHAR is a validation rule because someone cannot input an INT?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of data you will be storing to those fields and that's define what data type you should use.

Example: `name` field will be storing character (string literal) and hance can't be INT type and has to be `STRING` type which in SQL is `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`

Comment: what I'm confused over is whether VARCHAR sets a data type, a validation rule or both of these things. So in a way VARCHAR is a validation rule because someone cannot input an INT?

Comment: Well both way you can think of, since the data stored is string type you will have to choose VARCHAR as datatype for that field and when you have set VARCHAR as datatype; your sql engine make sure that you can't put a wrong type data in that field ... which is sure a validation. Hope this clears the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It defines only the data type. If wrong data type is passed, depending on server settings, an implisit conversion of the data is performed (most cases) or the query is rejected (example: MySQL's STRICT mode). Data validation is usually done in the application or in a trigger.